# Form object undefined when using Angularjs blockUI

Tags: angularjs, blockui

I'm using Angularjs, version 1.5, and i have specified a form in my html as follows:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="showForm">
<form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm" novalidate role="form">
</form>
</div>
```

In the corresponding controller i have a function that resets the form and calls pristine:

```
$scope.myForm.$setPristine();
```

Until now everything works fine.

I then try to use blockUI (https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui)
by changing the above div to:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="showForm" block-ui="myBlock">
```

so the only addition is: block-ui="myBlock"

however, when the controller code runs i get:

TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined

When debugging i see that the form object does not exist! When removing block-ui="myBlock", everything works fine again.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at form example: http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/examples/focus-management

Comment: Yep...it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like these:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout, blockUI) {

  $scope.form = {};

  $scope.submit = function() {
    var myBlockUI = blockUI.instances.get('myForm');

    $scope.form.myForm.$setPristine();
    myBlockUI.start();

    $timeout(function() {
      // Stop the block after some async operation.
      myBlockUI.stop();
    }, 3000);
  };
}
```

and view:

```
<form name="form.myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()" block-ui="myForm">
  <input type="text">
    <button>
       Submit
    </button>
  </form>
```

I have same trouble like you with `undefined` form on `$scope`, but found these trick with using additional object `form` on SO. Plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MXOJjP2iEXqjsbjzHutd).

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to solve my problem by passing the form object as an argument through form's button:    <button> type="button" ng-click=myFunction(myForm)</button>